# Why am I getting Type mismatch error?

Tags: java, generics

I have been trying to return a Map using generics:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class GenericTest {

    public <T extends Vehicle> Map<String, T> get() {
        Map<String, Car> map = new HashMap<>();
        return map; // Getting error 
    }

}    
class Vehicle {
}    
class Car extends Vehicle {
}
```

In the line, where I am returning map , i am getting error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,Car> to Map<String,T>
```

Could somebody explain why??

In the return type I have mentioned that T extends Vehicle.

Comment: `T` is determined by the **caller** - that is what a generic method _means_.

Answer (score 6):

Because you can call `Map<String, Truck> map = new GenericTest().get();`. And a `Map<String, Car>` isn't a `Map<String, Truck>`.

Change the variable declaration to:

```
Map<String, T> map = new HashMap<>();
```

or change the method signature to:

```
public Map<String, Car> get()
```

Comment: Or just `return new HashMap<>()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider well, yes. But it's the `Car` which is the immediate problem, not the fact a variable is declared.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common misconception that generic parameters are determined by the callee (the method), not the caller.

In fact, generic parameters are determined by the caller i.e. when you call the method:

```
Map<String, Bus> myMap = get(); // Now "T" is "Bus".
```

That's why the error occurs. As the caller, I can specify any `Vehicle` as `T`, but the method can only return a `Map<String, Car>`, which is incompatible with `Map<String, Bus>`.

To do what you want to do, change the return type to `Map<String, ? extends Vehicle>`.

Answer (score 1):

you are defining return type as generics but returning concrete object's map. According to your method signature `public <T extends Vehicle> Map<String, T> get()` you could assign returned value to map of any subclass of `Vehicle` as value and `key` as `String` but since you are returning `Map<String, Car>` you could not do that.

so you need to change map to `Map<String, T> map = new HashMap<>()`

Answer (score 0):

public class GenericTest {

```
public <T extends Vehicle> Map<String, T> get() {
    Map<String, T> map = new HashMap<>();
    return map;
}
```

}

class Vehicle {
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
}

**Then you call the method like this**
Map map = new GenericTest().get();

Comment: Not only is this answer unhelpful, but it also has rawtypes in a question about generics! `Map map`.